# How to Separate Wordpress Query Result by Taxonomy with Heading?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have a wordpress custom post type of "awards", which has a custom taxonomy of "awardyear." I'm trying to write a query that will list them all out, but group them by year, and have the year in a heading. For example all of the awards from the year 2010 would be grouped together & have "2010" as the header. Is this even possible? I'm able to get them all listed out, however, it's currently listing them all out under each year. Here is my current query:

```
$taxonomy = 'awardyear';
$queried_term = get_query_var($taxonomy);
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy, 'slug='.$queried_term);

$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'awards',
'posts_per_page' => -1 ,
'awardyear' => $term->name,
'order_by' => 'awardyear',
'order' => 'ASC'    
 );

if ($terms) {
  foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo '<span class="award_year">' . $term->name . '</span> ';
    query_posts( $args );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li style="list-style: none;">';
    echo '<a href="';
    the_permalink();
    echo '">';
    the_title();
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();

  }
}
```

Example output would be:

```
2010
Award Example Number 1
Award Example Number 2

2011
Award Example Number 1
Award Example Number 2
Award Example Number 3
Award Example Number 4

2012
Award Example Number 1
Award Example Number 2
Award Example Number 3
```

Comment: Your explanation seems a little vague.  could you explain and show example on how you would like the output to look like?

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify my goal output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `$args['awardyear']` gets set, once, before `$term` is defined and will therefore be undefined itself. Remove it from the definition of `$args` and put `$args['awardyear'] = $term->name;` at the top of your `foreach` loop. That way it will be set correctly on each past.

Please note that this sort of use of `query_posts()` is generally frowned upon; see the Codex entry for that function.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider doing it a different way as post meta would be a better choice on actually accomplishing what you want effectively.

Although regardless if you really want to use the taxonomy you will need to do it based on a query that takes the taxonomy columns and you can display it from there.

Reference: http://scribu.net/wordpress/sortable-taxonomy-columns.html

Comment: No, that didn't work either. That printed the year, like it was supposed to, but then after that it listed all of the awards. Not just the ones from that year. Thanks for your effort though. Much appreciated